# How to change Button font size in localization condition with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, nslocalizedstring, nslocale

I have two language versions(English, Chinese) in my app. I would like to change button language text into these languages when user click on "Change Language" button. 
For example,

```
 btnLogOut.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Logout", comment: ""), for: .normal)
```

In Chinese language, the text does not show completely. So, I would like to change the font size when button text is translated into Chinese. 
 
I don't want to change font size in English version. The Default font size for this button is "System Font. 15"

```
btnLogOut.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Logout", comment: ""), for: .normal, UIFont.buttonFontSize) <br>
```

I got error. Actually , I added as a testing. I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: based on condition you can use :
 UIButton().titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)

Comment: @ankit,  If we add like this, this font size 13 will also effect to English Language, right? I don't want to change font size in English Language. I just only want to change in Chinese Language.

Comment: @MayPhyu have you tried changing the font size whenever the user taps on "Change Language" and it is on Chinese?

Comment: @MayPhyu have you tried the `button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` ?

Comment: Bro @aircraft, I add that code. It works ! thanks bro

Comment: @MayPhyu You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one way is to check when the user changes the language. For example,

```
changeLanguage() // change language

if currentLanguage == "Chinese" {
    buttonLogout.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
} else {
    buttonLogout.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
}
enter code here
```

Depending on how you implement the changing of language, you can have some kind of flag that checks whatever the current language is then change the font size to what you want.

Or another way is:

```
buttonLogout.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: Bro @Cuevas, Your second way works for me. Thanks bro.

Comment: bro @Cuevas, How can I detect the language in iOS swift ?